# How to stop Quarkus 3 from blocking changes to maven repository?

Tags: maven, quarkus

A running instance of quarkus 3.x is blocking all changes to any libraries in the local maven repository that is used by that quarkus.

This was no problem with quarkus 2.x - but now, any maven task that wants to for example update a library from the central maven repostiry fails.

Example:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-maven-goal: Could not resolve dependencies for project my-maven-jar:jar:99.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
some-library-also-used-by-runningquarkus:jar:99.0.0-SNAPSHOT (present): Could not transfer artifact some-library-also-in-by-runningquarkus:jar:99.0.0-20230713.110758-868: 
C:\m2_repository\path-to-some-library\99.0.0-SNAPSHOT\some-library-also-used-by-runningquarkus-99.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.7679739696874598221.tmp -> 
C:\m2_repository\path-to-some-library\99.0.0-SNAPSHOT\some-library-also-used-by-runningquarkus-99.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

How can the previous behavior (not blocking the local maven repo) be achieved?

Comment: This is odd. And when you stop the Quarkus app, you can publish things again? I don’t know if there’s an equivalent of lsof on Windows but it would be interesting to see the list of files open by the Quarkus app.

Comment: Also is this in dev mode or when running a jar?

Comment: Do you have a antivirus software running? If so check if that is related because sometimes antivirus assumes something wrong with builded artifacts... the other question is why is your location changed?

Comment: I am running the quarkus in dev mode.


If a location in the error is changed, then I messed up the anonymizing (path contained company name).


I have the same problem on two systems with one only windows defender, the other (company system) with a different anti virus.